# Putting a content below of the absolute position?

Tags: html, css

I would lite to create the navigation link of my fixed sidebar, however after putting an absolute position on the first div. The next content dint goes under the first content. can anyone help to fix this? placing the text (WELCOME) below of the first div content? I tried to use justify content but I failed,

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}


/* Custom Desingn
 use rem instead of pixels  */

.sideprofile {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 29rem;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
}

.profileLogo {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: .6rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.profile {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 18rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #FF5733 #3383FF #12AB86 #ABAB12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: profileAnimated 5s linear infinite;
  background-color: #F1F3F3;
}

.welcome {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Keyframes to animate*/

@keyframes profileAnimated {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sideprofile">
  <div class="profileLogo">
    <div class="profile"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="welcome">WELCOME</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `absolute` positioning, you should consider adding the same amount (`190px`) of padding.

```css
.sideprofile {
  padding-top: 190px;
}
```

Working Snippet:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}


.sideprofile {
  height: 100%;
  width: 29rem;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  padding-top: 190px;
}

.profileLogo {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: .6rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.profile {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 18rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #FF5733 #3383FF #12AB86 #ABAB12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: profileAnimated 5s linear infinite;
  background-color: #F1F3F3;
}

.welcome {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Keyframes to animate*/

@keyframes profileAnimated {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sideprofile">
  <div class="profileLogo">
    <div class="profile"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="welcome">WELCOME</h1>
</div>
```